# cordova Android Studio unable to run application, no module?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

Something happend today with my Android studio program, I can no longer run any applications through it.
[image]

I've tried restalling it and everything, but i cannot get an android installation in there. As you can see next to the build icon, it's empty. Any help is greatly appreciated.

and yes, i've set ANDROID_HOME

[image]